# Optimizely CMS 12 : Blank page after CMS Upgrade

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0, episerver, optimizely

I'm working on upgrading a site from CMS 11 to 12. It is landing on a blank page.
It is not throwing any error. Don't know why epi returns a blank page.

Blank Page Content:[Blankpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQRhp.jpg)

It has to land on Start Page which is likely a homepage.
I tried debugging the code ,but break point never hits StartPage Controller. Some where flow is breaking and never goes to controller, returns a blank page.

Here is my startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostingEnvironment;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment webHostingEnvironment, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _webHostingEnvironment = webHostingEnvironment;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (_webHostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", Path.Combine(_webHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "App_Data"));

            services.Configure<SchedulerOptions>(options => options.Enabled = false);
        }

        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddResponseCaching();

        services
            //.AddCmsAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddCms()
            .AddAlloy() //Service collections Extensions
            .AddFind()
            //.AddAdminUserRegistration()
            .AddEmbeddedLocalization<Startup>();

        services.AddCors(opt =>
        {
            opt.AddPolicy(name: "CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
      services.AddContentDeliveryApi();
      services.AddAlloyHideTabs();

        // Required by Wangkanai.Detection to handle multiple devices
        services.AddDetection();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Strict;
            options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "okta.auth";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie("okta.auth", options =>
            {
                options.Events.OnSignedIn = async ctx =>
                {
                    if (ctx.Principal?.Identity is ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity)
                    {
                        // Syncs user and roles so they are available to the CMS
                        var synchronizingUserService = ctx
                            .HttpContext
                            .RequestServices
                            .GetRequiredService<ISynchronizingUserService>();

                        await synchronizingUserService.SynchronizeAsync(claimsIdentity);
                    }
                };
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "okta.auth";
                options.SignOutScheme = "okta.auth";
                options.ClientId = _configuration["Okta:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = _configuration["Okta:ClientSecret"];
                options.Authority = _configuration["Okta:Authority"];
                options.SignedOutCallbackPath = _configuration["Okta:PostLogoutRedirectUrl"];
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
                options.Scope.Add(_configuration["Okta:Scopes"]);
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "groups"
                };

                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = async context =>
                    {
                        var contentLoader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();
                        var urlResolver = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UrlResolver>();

                        var startPage = contentLoader.Get<StartPage>(ContentReference.StartPage);

                        if (context.Request.Path.Value != null && !context.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().Contains("episerver"))
                        {
                            context.Response.Redirect($"{startPage.LoginPage.GetPublicUrl().TrimEnd('/')}?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(context.Request.GetEncodedUrl())}");
                            context.HandleResponse();
                        }

                        if (ContentReference.StartPage.ID != 0 && context.Exception.Message.Contains("User is not assigned to the client application"))
                        {
                            context.Response.Redirect($"{urlResolver.GetUrl(startPage.LoginPage)}?loginErrorMessage={Uri.EscapeDataString("User is not assigned to the client application. Make sure the user is assigned to the application or to a group assigned to the application in Okta.")}");
                            context.HandleResponse();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync(context.Exception.Message);

                            context.HandleResponse();
                        }
                        await Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
                        {
                            context.HandleResponse();
                        }

                        // If signing out, add the id_token_hint
                        if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                        {
                            var idTokenHint = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken);

                            if (idTokenHint != null)
                            {
                                context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                            }

                            context.HandleResponse();

                            await Task.CompletedTask;
                            return;
                        }

                        var contentLoader = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IContentLoader>();

                        if (ContentReference.StartPage.ID != 0)
                        {
                            var startPage = contentLoader.Get<StartPage>(ContentReference.StartPage);
                            var loginPageUrl = startPage.LoginPage.GetPublicUrl();

                            if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().Contains("episerver") && startPage.LoginPage == null)
                            {
                                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                                context.HandleResponse();
                                return;
                            }

                            if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().Contains("episerver") && context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Epi-Auth-Flow"] == null)
                            {
                                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect($"{loginPageUrl.TrimEnd('/')}?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(context.HttpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl())}");
                                context.HandleResponse();
                                return;
                            }
                        }

                        HandleMultiSiteReturnUrl(context);

                        if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 401 && context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                            context.HandleResponse();
                            return;
                        }

                        if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 401 && IsXhrRequest(context.HttpContext.Request))
                        {
                            context.HandleResponse();
                            return;
                        }

                        //context.HandleResponse();
                        await Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
                    {
                        // Handle authorization code received
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    OnTokenValidated = (ctx) =>
                    {
                        var redirectUri = new Uri(ctx.Properties.RedirectUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                        if (redirectUri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                        {
                            ctx.Properties.RedirectUri = redirectUri.PathAndQuery;
                        }

                        //// Sync user and the roles to EPiServer in the background
                        //var synchronizingUserService = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ISynchronizingUserService>();
                      

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddMemoryCache();

        services.AddTransient<IOktaServices>(serviceProvider => new OktaServices(serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>()!));

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.CacheProfiles.Add("PageControllerBaseOutputCacheProfile", new CacheProfile
            {
                Duration = 0,  // Cache duration in seconds. Set to 0 for no caching.
                Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None,
                NoStore = true
            });
        });
       
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // Required by Wangkanai.Detection
        app.UseDetection();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
         endpoints.MapControllers();
         endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapContent();
        });

        // Map the "/util/logout.aspx" endpoint
        app.Map("/util/logout", map =>
        {
            map.Run(async context =>
            {
                // Sign out the user
                await context.SignOutAsync();

                if (ContentReference.StartPage.ID == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var contentLoader = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IContentLoader>();
                var urlResolver = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UrlResolver>();

                var startPage = contentLoader.Get<StartPage>(ContentReference.StartPage);

                // Redirect to the start page
                context.Response.Redirect(
                    $"{context.Request.Scheme}://{context.Request.Host}{urlResolver.GetUrl(startPage)}");
            });
        });
    }

    public void ConfigureContainer(ServiceCollection context)
    {
        //Register custom implementations that should be used in favor of the default implementations
        context.AddTransient<IContentRenderer, ErrorHandlingContentRenderer>()
            .AddTransient<ContentAreaRenderer, AlloyContentAreaRenderer>()
            .AddTransient<IMessageSender, SmtpSender>();
    }

    private static bool IsXhrRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        const string xRequestedWith = "X-Requested-With";

        var query = request.Query;
        if (query.ContainsKey(xRequestedWith) && query[xRequestedWith] == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            return true;
        }

        var headers = request.Headers;
        return headers.ContainsKey(xRequestedWith) && headers[xRequestedWith] == "XMLHttpRequest";
    }

    private void HandleMultiSiteReturnUrl(RedirectContext context)
    {
     

        if (context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri == null)
        {
            var currentUrl = context.HttpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl();
            context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = currentUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ServiceCollection Class

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddAlloy(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new SiteViewEngineLocationExpander()));


        services.Configure<TinyMceConfiguration>(config =>
        {
            config.Default().AddSetting("extended_valid_elements",
                    "iframe[src|alt|title|width|height|align|name],picture,source[srcset|media],span")
                .AddPlugin(
                    "epi-link epi-image-editor epi-dnd-processor epi-personalized-content print preview searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor " +
                    "wordcount imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern help code")
                .Toolbar(
                    "bold italic strikethrough forecolor | epi-link image epi-image-editor epi-personalized-content | imagevault-insert-media imagevault-edit-media | bullist numlist | searchreplace fullscreen ",
                    "styleselect formatselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | removeformat | table toc | code"
                    , "")
                .Menubar("edit insert view format table tools help")
                .BodyClass("main-content-wrapper")
                .AddSetting("image_title", false)
                .AddSetting("image_dimensions", true);
        });

        services.AddTinyMceSpellChecker();

        services.Configure<DisplayOptions>(displayOption =>
        {
            displayOption.Add("full", "/displayoptions/full", Global.ContentAreaTags.FullWidth, string.Empty, "epi-icon__layout--full");
            displayOption.Add("wide", "/displayoptions/wide", Global.ContentAreaTags.TwoThirdsWidth, string.Empty, "epi-icon__layout--two-thirds");
            displayOption.Add("half", "/displayoptions/half", Global.ContentAreaTags.HalfWidth, string.Empty, "epi-icon__layout--half");
            displayOption.Add("narrow", "/displayoptions/narrow", Global.ContentAreaTags.OneThirdWidth, string.Empty, "epi-icon__layout--one-third");
        });


        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => options.Filters.Add<PageContextActionFilter>());

        services.AddDisplayResolutions();
        services.AddDetection();

        return services;
    }

    private static void AddDisplayResolutions(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<StandardResolution>();
        services.AddSingleton<IpadHorizontalResolution>();
        services.AddSingleton<IphoneVerticalResolution>();
        services.AddSingleton<AndroidVerticalResolution>();
    }
}
```

Comment: You startup miss `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{` after     `app.UseAuthorization();`

Comment: Can you browse to the start page, i.e. click it in edit mode and preview it?

Comment: Yes @TedNyberg, Able to browse start page in edit mode.
Issue is only when application starts, it is not landing on a start page.

Comment: Does the start page have a house icon in the page tree? In other words, is it properly configured under "Manage websites" for the host name?

Comment: Yes @TedNyberg, hostname is properly configured under Manage websites option.

Comment: @QingGuo, It's copy paste mistake. I have updated code.

Comment: @TedNyberg, I'm suspecting the issue with **AddOpenIdConnect** . If it is commented I am able to launch start page. We may need to call AddOpenIdConnect on condition based, such that it calls for only Edit Page not for the start page. 
Could you please share your thoughts on this.